# Efficient way to query and update A[L]*1 + A[L+1]*2 ... + A[R]*(R-L+1)

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, brute-force

We are given an *array* **A[N]**, and we are asked to perform the following 3 types of queries on the given array:

> **1 L R**
>
> **2 L R**
>
> **3 X Y**
>
> **Query 1**, *Calculate*:  ***A[L] x 1 + A[L + 1] x 2 + ........ + A[R] x (R - L+ 1)***
>
> **Query 2**, *Calculate*:  ***A[L] x (R - L + 1) +..........+ A[R - 1] x 2 + A[R] x 1***
>
> **Query 3**, *Update*:    ***A[X] = Y***

***Inputs***:

> ***N*** and ***Q***, where **N** is the number of elements in the array, and **Q** is the number of queries.
>
> The next line contains **N** elements of the array.
>
> Next **Q** lines contain queries in the format: **type L R**

***Outputs***:

> We have to print results for query types **1** and **2**.

***Constraints***:

1 <= N, Q <= 10^5

1 <= L <= R <= N

1 <= A[i] <= 10^9

***Sample TestCase***:

> ```
> Inputs:
>
> 5 4
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 1 1 2
> 2 1 2
> 3 2 1
> 1 1 2
>
> Output:
> 5
> 4
> 3
> ```

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class TestClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = scn.nextInt();   
            int q = scn.nextInt();
            int[] arr = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = scn.nextInt();
            }

            while (q-- > 0) {
                int type = scn.nextInt();    // type is for which type of query user enters.
                int l = scn.nextInt();
                int r = scn.nextInt();       
                long ans = 0;                   // ans variable i take it in long as answer may be grater.
                if (type == 1) {      
                    int count = 1;
                    while (l <= r) {
                        ans = ans + arr[l - 1] * count;  //Also in this array is started with index 1 not with 0 that means 0 index element is first element.
                        count++;
                        l++;
                    }
                    System.out.println(ans);  //Printing answer for query1.
                } else if (type == 2) {
                    int count = (r - l + 1);
                    while (l <= r) {
                        ans = ans + arr[l - 1] * count;
                        count--;
                        l++;
                    }
                    System.out.println(ans);  // Printing answer here for query 2.
                } else if (type == 3) {   
                    arr[l - 1] = r;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

***Code explanation:***

The above code is a simple brute force approach to calculate the results of the query ***type 1*** and ***type 2***, I  can't think of any algorithm or data structure to optimized the results of the query.

***Code Time Complexity :***  **O(Q x N)**

According to the ***constraints***, it looks like we have to result the query in **O( sqrt(N) )** or **O( log(N) )** time.

**How can we optimize type 1 and type 2 queries?**

Comment: If you need to process all the elements of the array then you can do it in _no less_ than `O(n)` time

Comment: @BoristheSpider, maybe we can use some DS which stores range[L, R] of results, like segment tree or BIT.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think we can query in O(1) time and O(n) space without the update queries; and O(log n) time, O(n) space with the update queries.

Comment: You’re going to take an `O(n*lg(n))` hit on population though - which is where the trade off happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have values:

```
0 1 2 3 4 (indexes)
a b c d e

a + 2b + 3c + 4d + 5e = S
```

To calculate query 1 for [1, 3] (zero-based):

```
S - a - 5e - (b + c + d)
```

To calculate query 1 for  [2, 4] (zero-based):

```
S - (a + 2b) - (2c + 2d + 2e)
```

So these kinds of queries can be answered in `O(1)` with preprocessing. We need two structures: one stores regular prefix sums:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

and the other the one with multipliers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 5, 14, 30, 55]
```

Since we need to also modify the prefix sums, we can use one segment tree for each type of prefix sum and then query and update in `O(log n)` time.

JavaScript code:

```js
// Adapted from https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18051
function build(t, n) {  // build the tree
  for (let i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) t[i] = t[i<<1] + t[i<<1|1];
}

function modify(t, p, value, n) {  // set value at position p
  for (t[p += n] = value; p > 1; p >>= 1) t[p>>1] = t[p] + t[p^1];
}

function query(t, l, r, n) {  // sum on interval [l, r)
  let res = 0;
  for (l += n, r += n; l < r; l >>= 1, r >>= 1) {
    if (l&1) res += t[l++];
    if (r&1) res += t[--r];
  }
  return res;
}
// End adaptation from https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18051


function main() {
  var A = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var Qs = [
    [1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 2]
  ];

  const n = A.length;
  const t0 = new Array(2 * (n + 1)).fill(0);
  const t1 = new Array(2 * (n + 1)).fill(0);
  const t2 = new Array(2 * (n + 1)).fill(0);

  // Build segment trees
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    t0[n + i] = A[i];
    t1[n + i] = (i + 1) * A[i];
    t2[n + i] = (n - i) * A[i];
  }
  build(t0, n);
  build(t1, n);
  build(t2, n);

  for (let [type, lx, ry] of Qs){
    // Adjust for non-zero-based indexes
    lx = lx - 1;
    ry = ry - 1;

    if (type == 1){
      let S = query(t1, 0, n + 1, n);
      let left = query(t1, 0, lx, n);
      let right = query(t1, ry + 1, n + 1, n);
      let subtrahend = lx * query(t0, lx, ry + 1, n);
      console.log(S - left - right - subtrahend);
    
    } else if (type == 2){
      let S = query(t2, 0, n + 1, n);
      let left = query(t2, 0, lx, n);
      let right = query(t2, ry + 1, n + 1, n);
      let subtrahend = (n - ry - 1) * query(t0, lx, ry + 1, n);
      console.log(S - left - right - subtrahend);

    } else {
      ry = ry + 1;
      modify(t0, lx, ry, n);
      modify(t1, lx, ry * (lx + 1), n);
      modify(t2, lx, ry * (n - lx), n);
    }
  }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

same code in python

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
Q = [
    [1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 2]
    ]


def preprocess():
    A0 = A.copy()
    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        A0[i+1] = A0[i] + A[i+1]
        
    A1 = A.copy()
    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        A1[i+1] = A1[i] + A[i+1]*(i+2)
        
    A2 = A.copy()
    A2[0] = A2[0]*len(A)
    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        A2[i+1] = A2[i] + A[i+1]*(len(A)-i-1)
    
    return A0,A1,A2
A0,A1,A2 = preprocess()

def query(arr, l,r):
    if r==-1:
        return 0
    if l==0:
        return arr[r]
    return arr[r]-arr[l-1]
    

for q in Q:
    if q[0]==1:
        l,r = q[1]-1,q[2]-1
        
        s = query(A1, 0, len(A)-1)
        left = query(A1, 0, l-1)
        right = query(A1, r+1, len(A)-1)
        middle = l*query(A0, l, r)
        
        print(s-left-right-middle)
    elif q[0]==2:
        l,r = q[1]-1,q[2]-1
        
        s = query(A2, 0,len(A)-1)
        left = query(A2, 0, l-1)
        right = query(A2, r+1, len(A)-1)
        middle = (len(A)-r-1)*query(A0, l, r)
        
        print(s-left-right-middle)
    else:
        l,r = q[1]-1, q[2]
        A[l]=r
        A1,A2,A3 = preprocess()
```